# Panda Sequence Grouping than flatern list column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have this DataFrame

```
data = [[1,'A','a','2020-01-01'],
        [1,'A','b','2020-01-02'],
        [1,'A','c','2020-01-03'],
        [1,'B','a','2020-01-04'],
        [1,'B','b','2020-01-05'],
        [2,'A','a','2020-01-06'],
        [2,'A','b','2020-01-07'],
        [2,'A','c','2020-01-08'],
        [2,'B','a','2020-01-09'],
        [2,'A','c','2020-01-10']]

        df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data = data,columns = ['id','Process','Process_sub_steps','date'])
```

output

```
       id Process Process_sub_steps        date
    0   1       A                 a  2020-01-01
    1   1       A                 b  2020-01-02
    2   1       A                 c  2020-01-03
    3   1       B                 a  2020-01-04
    4   1       B                 b  2020-01-05
    5   2       A                 a  2020-01-06
    6   2       A                 b  2020-01-07
    7   2       A                 c  2020-01-08
    8   2       B                 a  2020-01-09
    9   2       A                 c  2020-01-10
```

Desired Result

```
       id Process Process_sub_steps_lst   delta_date
    0   1       A             [a, b, c]       3 Days
    1   1       B                [a, b]       2 Days
    2   2       A             [a, b, c]       3 Days
    3   2       B                   [a]       1 Days
    4   2       A                   [c]       1 Days
```

If i just do a groupby

```
df_1.groupby("Process")["Process_sub_steps"].apply(lambda x: [z for y in x for z in y]).reset_index()
```

I will get this

```
  Process       Process_sub_steps
0       A   [a, b, c, a, b, c, c]
1       B               [a, b, a]
```

I don't want a total groupby just group elements consequently than flatten the next column and calculate the time delta between the sub processes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `list` to extract elements, and `max()-min()` (`np.ptp` also works) for durations:

```
# we will use this to detect changes in `id` and `Process`
tmp = df_1[['id','Process']]

(df_1.groupby(tmp.ne(tmp.shift()).any(1).cumsum())
   .agg({'id':'first', 
         'Process':'first',
         'Process_sub_steps':list, 
         'date':np.ptp})
)
```

Output:

```
   id Process Process_sub_steps   date
1   1       A         [a, b, c] 2 days
2   1       B            [a, b] 1 days
3   2       A         [a, b, c] 2 days
4   2       B               [a] 0 days
5   2       A               [c] 0 days
```

Comment: This code breaks if i add a new row in my data frame say [2,'A','a','2020-01-08','b'] this new row element goes at 2nd index and appends a new element in Process_sub_steps column but doesn't create a new row.

Comment: That's a different kind of grouping, not just on `id` and `processes`. Maybe you should mention it clearly in your post.

Answer (score 2):

Convert values to datetimes and then aggregate `list` by both columns with difference between maximal and minimal values for timedeltas:

```
df_1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['date'])

df = (df_1.groupby(['id','Process']).agg(Process_sub_steps_lst = ('Process_sub_steps',list),
                                        delta_date=('date',lambda x: x.max() - x.min()))
                                    .reset_index())
print (df)
   id Process Process_sub_steps_lst delta_date
0   1       A             [a, b, c]     2 days
1   1       B                [a, b]     1 days
2   2       A             [a, b, c]     2 days
3   2       B                   [a]     0 days
```

If need to add one day use:

```
df['delta_date'] += pd.Timedelta('1 days')
print (df)
   id Process Process_sub_steps_lst delta_date
0   1       A             [a, b, c]     3 days
1   1       B                [a, b]     2 days
2   2       A             [a, b, c]     3 days
3   2       B                   [a]     1 days
```

Comment: This code breaks if i add a new row in my data frame say [2,'A','a','2020-01-10''] this new row element goes at 2nd index and appends a new element in Process_sub_steps column but doesn't create a new row.